# Sending values through ajax, nothing happens in SQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have built this ajax function where i want to update two fields in a database if the user decides to change them, i have this code where i'am printing hotelrooms (school assignment) with their current information, ID, etcetera:

```
 <?php
        include('php/connect.php');

        $chquery = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
        $chresult = mysqli_query($conn, $chquery);

        while($chrow = mysqli_fetch_array($chresult)){
            echo "<div class='edit_roomRow'>";
            echo "<h1> Rum " . $chrow['ID'] . "</h1>";
            echo "<form>";
            echo "Rumsnummer:<br> <input id='c-roomnumber' type='text' value = '" . $chrow['ID'] . "' placeholder='" . $chrow['ID'] . "'><br>";
            echo "Beskrivning:<br> <input id='c-description' type='text' value = '" . $chrow['Description'] . "'placeholder='" . $chrow['Description'] . "'>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='btn btn-warning change-btn' data-value='". $chrow['ID'] . "'style='float: right; margin-top: 100px;'>Ändra</div>";
            echo "<hr/>";
        }

        mysqli_free_result($chresult);

        mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Here nothing is wrong and all values seem correct.
Then here's the ajax where i send the info from this form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".change-btn").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("data-value");
        var description = $("#c-description").val();
        var roomnumber = $("#c-roomnumber").val();
        //Call to ajax
        $.ajax({
            method:"GET",
            url: "php/changepost.php",
            data:{ id: id, description: description, roomnumber: roomnumber },
            success: function(){
                $(this).val("");
                $("#c-description").val("");
                $("#c-roomnumber").val("");
                //Reload specific div with rooms, avoid full page reload
                $(".changerooms").load(location.href + " .changerooms");
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

To make sure all the values are sent from the PHP (correct ID from the button, description & room number) i alerted them in the end of the ajax file, all values correct.

Then here i am trying to update the DB with the new values:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
include('connect.php');

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $changequery = "UPDATE rooms SET ID = $_GET['roomnumber'], Description = $_GET['description'] WHERE ID = $_GET['id']";
    //Perform $changequery
    mysqli_query($conn, $changequery);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

I cant see anything that is off here, but i am kind of new with AJAX mostly, so if you see something that seems wrong, i would be glad with any help i could get.. :)

Comment: Try changing you GET to POST in ajax and your $_GET to $_POST or put a die() right in the isset statement to see if it is actually getting to that point.

Comment: 1st: you need to alert returned data by using  success:function(data){alert(data);} and see if any errors .. 2nd: I think $(this) in success won't work so define ThisIt = $(this); in the beginning of the click event and then use ThisIt in success instead of $(this)

Comment: mysqli_query() return true or false?  GET parameter values are escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string syntax is wrong. If you don't use the curly syntax around variables, you mustn't put quotes around the array indexes. You also need quotes around string values in the SQL.

```
$changequery = "UPDATE rooms SET ID = $_GET[roomnumber], Description = '$_GET[description]' WHERE ID = $_GET[id]";
```

It would be better for you to learn to use prepared queries with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, to avoid SQL injection problems.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE rooms SET ID = ?, Description = ? WHERE ID = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isi", $_GET['roomnumber'], $_GET['description'], $_GET['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```